# Is there a way to execute selenium "queries" via commandline interactively?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to execute selenium "queries" via commandline interactively? Instead of creaticing a static file and run that I would like to execute selenium python code interactively via terminal. Is it possibile?

For example selenium browser opens up, and from terminal I write `driver.get("www.google.com")` and selenium browsers executes this. Then for example I write in terminal `driver.find_element("name", "test")` and selenium browsers do that etc etc.

Comment: You could write Python code to do it.  Read and interpret commands in your own interpreter loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always invoke the [python](/questions/tagged/python) shell with the following command in the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line):

```
python
```

and supply the following commands one by one:

- `from selenium import webdriver`
- `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
- `driver.get(url='https://www.google.com/')`

Snapshot:

[image: python_shell]

Comment: thank you very much. I don't know why I didn't think about it.